# Github repo file tree

Tags: git, github

I am new-ish to using github, and I have run into an issue that I can't figure out how to solve. Hopeful someone here can direct me to the correct answer. I am wanting to fork a person's Android ROM into my acct. Easy enough, just click fork....but, that isn't giving me what I want.  I am looking for a file tree like the following myAcct/ROM/theirRepos (there are multiple).  Anytime I tap fork on their Repos, I get myAcct/theirRepos.  Anyone have a solution to setting up a project like this?

Comment: I have it figured out. Neither of the comments was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you want to use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can only fork entire repositories. You probably want something else that's not solved by forking.

Comment: That, I know. They have somewhere near 25 repositories for a single project. I was wanting those 25+ repositories 'in' my project repository.

Comment: if you want those 25+ repositories, then you need to click fork 25+ times for each one of them